# Differentiating $f(z)=z^z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I feel as though I am extremely close with this problem, but I am having a hard time finishing it. The equation numbers I have listed are from the textbook *Complex Variables with Application* by A. David Wunsch.

> Let $f(z)=z^z$, where the principal branch is used. Evaluate $f'(z)$.

Using the principal branch and Eq. 3.6-1, I know $f(z)=z^z=e^{z\text{Log}(z)}.$ Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(z)&=&\frac{d}{dz}z^z\\
&=&\frac{zz^z}{z} \text{ by Eq. 3.6-2}\\
&=& \frac{ze^{z\text{Log}(z)}}{z}
\end{eqnarray*}
Using the principal branch and Eq. 3.6-1, I know $z=e^{\text{Log}(z)}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(z)&=&\frac{e^{\text{Log}(z)}e^{z\text{Log}(z)}}{e^{\text{Log}(z)}}\\
&=& e^{[1-1]\text{Log}z}e^{z\text{Log}(z)}\\
&=& e^{z\text{Log}(z)}
\end{eqnarray*}

Which is the incorrect solution, according to the back of the book. The correct solution is $e^{z\text{Log}(z)}[\text{Log}z+1]$. I am unsure as to where I went wrong. If someone could be please help me identify my mistake it would be much appreciated.

Comment: what does "Eq 3.6-2" say ?

Comment: You just have to use the chain rule once you changed $z^z$ by $e^{z Log(z)}$

Comment: It reads $\frac{d}{dz}z^c=\frac{cz^c}{z}$.

Comment: @JessieByrnes, the formula you just gave in a comment only holds when $c$ is *constant* with respect to the variable $z$.  You are trying to apply it to the variable itself.

Comment: @Eliana Thank you for pointing out the chain rule. That helped me solve the problem.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thank you for pointing out my error!

Comment: I have to ask, how come you don't conclude $\frac {z z^z} z = z^z$ before substitution and voodoo with $z^z = e^{z\operatorname{Log}z}$?

Comment: I did...but I thought it was an incorrect since I was not getting the right answer so I switched to substitution and as you call it "voodoo." Since I got the same result using this method, I now know for sure that concluding $\frac{zz^z}{z}=z^z$ was correct. This is how I knew I must have made an error somewhere else. It was very roundabout I know. I left it in there to show that I did make an attempt at this problem before posting.

Comment: Well, you got $e^{z\operatorname{Log}z} = z^z = \frac{zz^z}{z}$, thus that whole roundabout is just an elaborate canceling of fractions. This really should have told you that $\frac{zz^z}{z}$ is wrong. Of course, an attempt is appreciated, but I just want to say that canceling of fractions should be trusted more than using principal branches.

Comment: I appreciate your insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you applied something like $$\frac d {dz} z^a=a z^{a-1}=\frac {a z^a}z$$ which is correct if $a$ is not a function of $z$.

You could have made the problem simpler using logarithmic differentiation $$f(z)=z^z \implies \log(f(z))=z \log(z)$$ Now, differentiating and using chain rule, $$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z}=\log (z)+1$$ which makes $$f'(z)=(\log (z)+1)z^z$$ as given in the textbook.